# sysout in JSP eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, editor, content-assist

**Eclipse Specific :  content assist**

**Problem statement:**

if I type sysout in JSP and press ctrl+spacebar then it should expand to System.out.println

**Description**

I am using sysout in Java for quite some time. but whenever I tried to use sysout in JSP 
I am getting error as content assist is not available at this location

I have also tried to insert template for JSP editor for sysout(Copied from template of Java Editor) but still I am getting same error.

Can anyone please suggest solution or any references where I can get help.

Comment: sound slike you could do with a hot deploy envirnment set up and avoid using scriptlets

Comment: You're doing something wrong. [Java code doesn't belong in JSP files, but in Java classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you love shortcuts:

```
syso is a shortcut for sysout
```

Hey, you can define a jsp-template with value

(window->preferences->web->jspfiles->editor->templates)

```
<%System.out.println("${cursor}");%>
```

So you can switch to JSP-Templates using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I found that I was not aware of ctrl + Spacebar +Spacebar command that`s why I could not find my template as well.. thanks for detailed info..

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I also found one more way
If you turn on Snippets view(Windows-->Views-->other-->Snippets) and if I copy the statement

```
System.out.println();
```

and right click on snippets view and select paste as snippet and create snippet it also does the work only difference being if i want to include sysout I need to double click on the snippet.

Comment: Or use drag and drop.

Answer (score -1):

Java Templates are not offered in the JSP Editor.  That's currently working as designed.