# In Eclipse how can I make sysout work inside a JSP scriplet

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, autocomplete

In Eclipse (version 2021-09) I would like to use the sysout template in the scriptlet area of a JSP page.

So, in my JSP editor I have:

```
...

<%
...
[cursor here]
...
%>
...
```

When I now type  `sysout`  how can I make it  expand to `System.out.println("[cursor here]");`?

I tried a new JSP template like this:

[image: New Tpl in Eclipse for sysout]

But it does not work *inside* the scriplet tags.

---

PS: I saw the question [sysout in JSP eclipse - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599836/sysout-in-jsp-eclipse), but the answers do not cover the case *inside* the scriptlet tags.

Comment: why would you sysout from a servlet?  there is maybe no output window.

Comment: The message will probably appear on stdout of the JVM not on the page. Also, is there any content assist for `System.out.` inside scriptlets?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Standard  out is written to Tomcats console window - great for a quick debug! :-)

Comment: Content Assist in scriptlets is solely for Java, and Java templates aren't supported there. You'll have to open a feature request.

Answer (score -3):

go to the preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist
at the bottom: "auto activation triggers for Java" and put in:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).